# Add custom field to Attribute page

Tags: attributes

Is there any clean way to add custom field to all product attributes in Magento?
`Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> (Add new/Edit) Attribute` page.

Something like it can be done for catalog category:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup("core_setup");
// below code will add text attribute
$setup->addAttribute("catalog_category", "attribute_code", array(
"group"         => "General",
"input"         => "text",
"type"          => "varchar",
"label"         => "Attribute label",
"backend"       => "",
"visible"       => 1,
"required"      => 0,
"user_defined" => 1,
"global"        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

There is no record in eav_entity_type table for attributes, so i can not use this method.
Is there any suggestion on the best way for adding this custom field for attributes.

Comment: What you do there for the category is adding an attribute for the category. This can be done for products as well (adding attributes for products -> just in the backend). What you want is to "add attributes to eav attributes". In pseudo code something like `addAttribute('eav_attribute' ...`)`

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your comment. What class should I use to add a custom field to attribute edit page this way. Using the example above $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup("core_setup");
// below code will add text attribute
$setup->addAttribute("eav_attribute", "attribute_code", array(...) I receiving Wrong entity ID error. I am new to Magento so it is not clear for me.

Comment: Hi, a bit confused by your question. Are you asking how to add an attribute to a product? Or how to add a new option field to the admin backend attribute editor?

Comment: Just to confirm: Have you have tried Alex's suggestion $setup->addAttribute("catalog_product","your_attribute_code", with the rest as you already posted it.

Answer (score 3):

> There is no record in eav_entity_type table for attributes

The only attribute connection in the `eav_entity_type` table is a field (`addition_attribute_table`) which points to  additional attribute metadata for each type.

The fields in the `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` create/edit views are attribute metadata and map to the columns in the `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute` tables. The  canonical attribute record and cross-entity metadata are in the former table, while catalog attribute metadata are in the latter table.

In order to have another field in the referenced view, you either need to rewrite the [`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Main`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Main.php#L35) class *or* (more flexibly) add another tab which contains the input for your custom field. You will also need to add your column to the `catalog_eav_attribute` table.

You might want to rewrite the [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Collection.php#L35) model if you need to conveniently apply filtering conditions based on your field, and you might consider rewriting [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::_prepareValues()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L43) if you want to specify a default value for your field.

Pretty neat!